# Converting WebSockets in Play framework from version 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.6, playframework-webservice

I'm trying to convert this code, that uses the Play version 2.4 to the current version (2.6) and I'm having some issues because I'm still a noob in Scala.

```
def wsWeatherIntervals = WebSocket.using[String] {
  request =>
    val url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Amsterdam,nl"
    val outEnumerator = Enumerator.repeatM[String]({
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      ws.url(url).get().map(r => s"${new java.util.Date()}\n ${r.body}")
    })
    (Iteratee.ignore[String], outEnumerator)
}
```

I followed [this guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/StreamsMigration25), but now I'm stuck on the stuff that I should return on the method.
This is the code that I'm trying to run using the version 2.6:

```
  import play.api.mvc._
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import akka.stream.scaladsl._
  def wsWeatherIntervals = WebSocket.accept[String, Future[String]] { res =>
    val url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Amsterdam,nl"
    val source = Source.repeat({
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      ws.url(url).get().map(r => s"${new java.util.Date()}\n ${r.body}")
    })
    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, source)
  }
```

But I'm getting this error when running the server, that points to the first line of the method:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter transformer: play.api.mvc.WebSocket.MessageFlowTransformer[String,scala.concurrent.Future[String]]
```

Note: I also tried to call `WebSocket.apply` instead of `WebSocket.accept` and I did some search about the differences between the two but didn't find anything useful. Can someone explain the difference between the two? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superficial error is that Play doesn't know how to turn a `Future[String]` into a Websocket message, for which you'd normally use an implicit transformer. However, in this case you don't want to return a `Future[String]` anyway but just a plain string which can be automatically marshalled (using the provided `stringMessageFlowTransformer` as it happens.) Here's something that should work:

```
def wsWeatherIntervals = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { res =>
  val url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Amsterdam,nl"
  def f = ws.url(url).get().map(r => s"${new java.util.Date()}\n ${r.body}")

  val source = Source.unfoldAsync(f)(last => {
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    f.map(next => Some((last, next)))
  })
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, source)
}
```

The `unfoldAsync` source lets us repeated run a function returning a future of the next element in the stream. (Since we want the stream to go on forever we return the value wrapped as `Some`.)

The `Websocket.apply` method is basically a more complicated version of `accept` which allows you to reject a websocket connection for some reason by returning a response, but if you need to do this it's better to use `acceptOrResult`, which handles transforming whatever your flow emits into websocket messages.